# How I develop webservice in spring that can be exposed as REST and SOAP both?

Tags: java, spring, rest, soap, spring-restcontroller

I have requirement to develop webservices in spring that should be in both form SOAP and REST.

So what is good way to write such code with minimum code duplication and write it with industry standards.

Pls provide some example or some helpful link.

Comment: Just a hint that may have nothing to do with your question, but if your planing to use security features you should use another stack. Not spring-ws as it does not support ws-policy.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [multi layer architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayered_architecture) where you have common business in service layer that are used by presentation layer (soap and rest). With spring it's realy easy to implement such architecutre